# Magento2 : how to get resize image for custom module

Tags: magento2, product-images, category-products

I have created custom module for get category's products which are assigned to particular category like "Featured Product". Feature product is a category and it has a many products. i got that array by developing custom module but i don't know how to get resized image for that product.

please help me
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below function to resize the product base image and get resized image URL.

```
public function __construct(
    ..
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $productContext,
    ...
) {    
    ...
    $this->productImageHelper = $productContext->getImageHelper();
    ...
}

function getImageUrl($productObject)
{
     $width = 180;
     $height = 180;

     $resizedImage = $this->productImageHelper
        ->init($productObject, 'product_base_image')
        ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
        ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
        ->keepTransparency(TRUE)
        ->keepFrame(TRUE)
        ->resize($width, $height)
        ->getUrl();

      return $resizedImage;
}
```

Comment: i have got this error "Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined property: $productImageHelper"

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: i have done this in different way and i got resized image but i dont want that i want default resize image like  this path "http://site_url/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/small_image/200x200/f6dddda10fc5ad2c97dfe792a3b67ce2/placeholder/default/logo.png"
so my mean that i want to get resize image from cache